# Returning Json object from controller action to jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, controller

I'm attempting to get this working properly (2 days now). I'm working on a log in where I'm calling the controller action from jQuery, passing it a JSON object (utilizing json2.js) and returning a Json object from the controller. I'm able to call the action fine, but instead of being able to put the response where I want it it just opens a new window with this printed on the screen:

```
{"Message":"Invalid username/password combination"}
```

And the URL looks like *http://localhost:13719/Account/LogOn* so instead of calling the action and not reloading the page it's taking the user to the controller, which isn't good.

So now for some code, first the controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl = "")
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var login = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<PhotographerLogin>>();

        var user = login.FindOne(x => x.Login == model.Username && x.Pwd == model.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return Json(new FailedLoginViewModel { Message = "Invalid username/password combination" });
        else
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) 
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            else 
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

And the jQuery code

```
$("#signin_submit").click(function () {
    var login = getLogin();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Account/LogOn",
        data: JSON.stringify(login),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr) {
            $("#message").text(xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
});

function getLogin() {
    var un = $("#username").val();
    var pwd = $("#password").val();
    var rememberMe = $("#rememberme").val();

    return (un == "") ? null : { Username: un, Password: pwd, RememberMe: rememberMe };
}
```

In case you need to see the actual login form here that is as well

```
<fieldset id="signin_menu">
    <div>
        <span id="message"></span>
    </div>
    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>    
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "signin" }))
        {%>

        <% ViewContext.FormContext.ValidationSummaryId = "valLogOnContainer"; %>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username) %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "inputbox", @tabindex = "4", @id = "username" })%><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "*")%>
        <p>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Password) %>
        <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "inputbox", @tabindex = "5", @id = "password" })%><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "*")%>
        </p>
        <p class="remember">
        <input id="signin_submit" value="Sign in" tabindex="6" type="submit"/>
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "inputbox", @tabindex = "7", @id = "rememberme" })%>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
        <p class="forgot"> <a href="#" id="forgot_password_link" title="Click here to reset your password.">Forgot your password?</a> </p>
        <p class="forgot-username"> <a href="#" id="forgot_username_link" title="Fogot your login name? We can help with that">Forgot your username?</a> </p>
        </p>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummaryJQuery("Please fix the following errors.", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valLogOnContainer" } })%>
    <% } %>
</fieldset>
```

The login form is loaded on the main page with

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("LogonControl");%>
```

Not sure if that has any bearing on this or not but thought I'd mention it.

**EDIT:** The login form is loaded similar to the Twitter login, click a link and the form loads with the help of jQuery & CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about what @user350374 said about making the signature of my action *JsonResult* instead of *ActionResult* I did some tinkering and modified my original solution to utilize *JsonResult* and did all the checking/redirecting in jQuery instead of in the action.

My action changed to

```
[HttpPost,MoveFormsScript]
public JsonResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl = "")
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var login = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<PhotographerLogin>>();

        var user = login.FindOne(x => x.Login == model.Username && x.Pwd == model.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return Json(new LoginResult { Success = false, Message = "Invalid login" });
        else
        {
            return Json(new LoginResult
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Redirecting...",
                ReturnUrl = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) ? returnUrl : string.Format("Account/Index/{0}", user.Photographer.Key)
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new LoginResultDTO { Success = false, Message = "Incomplete fields" });
    }

}
```

And my jQuery call to

```
$("#signin_submit").click(function () {
    var f = $($("form")[0]);
    f.submit(function () {
        var loginData = f.serialize();
        $.post(f.attr("action"), loginData, function (result, status) {
            if (!result.Success) {
                $("#message").text(result.Message);

                $("#username").focus();
                $("#username").select();
            }
            else {
                window.location.replace(result.ReturnUrl);
            }

        }, "json");
        return false;
    });
});
```

*LoginResult* is a simple class just to hold the parts

```
public class LoginResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the tip @user35037, now I have 2 ways to approach this in the future.

Comment: @psycho I had the same issue here. Besides the fact that the redirect as ActionResult wouldn't work when called through jQuery, the main reason your first code was returning the "json file" is because you haven't had the `return false;` in the submit function, thus, returning the JSON as a "file".

Answer (score 18):

Your action signature will look as follows:

```
public virtual JsonResult ActionName()
{
     var abcObj = new ABC{a=1,b=2};

     return Json(abcObj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have it as _ActionResult_ because if it's a valid login then I redirect to a view.

Comment: WEll you can return any one type from the server right and I think Json is the best cos you can serialize ur partial view as json and send it back to the client and probably append a isValid property to the json based on which u choose wat to render on the page.

Comment: Also if that is not something that you dont want to consider what you can do is if the user login successfully u trigger another call frm js that gets the partial view

Answer (score 10):

If you're using MVC 2, you have to return something like this :

```
return Json(your_object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I've found it [here](http://www.ifunky.net/blog/post/AspNet-MVC-2-JsonRequestBehaviorAllowGet.aspx)

For a different usage, here is my code.

JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#InputDate").live('click', function () {
        var date = $("#InputDate").val();
        if (date != "") {
            $.getJSON("/Home/GetNames",
                    { date: $("#InputDate").val() },
                    function (data) {
                        $("#ProviderName").empty();
                        // [...]
                        });
                    });
        }
    });
});
```

And C#

```
public JsonResult GetNames(string date)
 {
   List<Provider> list = new List<Provider>();
   // [...]
   return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Kerrubin, It is not only for MVC2 , It is for MVC 3,4 and 5

Answer (score 2):

Ok came up with a resolution that I thought I'd share here in case someone comes along with a simliar issue. Instead of using *$.ajax* I switched to using *$.post* and changed my jQuery code to look like this and everything works just the way I initially expected it to:

```
$("#signin_submit").click(function () {
    var f = $($("form")[0]);
    f.submit(function () {
        var loginData = f.serialize();
        $.post(f.attr("action"), loginData, function (result, status) {
            if (!result.Success) {
                $("#message").text(result.Message);
            }
        }, "json");
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Thanks to all who looked at my question, and to @kerrubin as I was unaware of that issue.