# Retrieve JSON data from MVC Controllers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to retrieve JSOn data from controller and set it for `window.location`.

in jquery :

```
 $('.starcontainer').rating(function (vote, event) {
        var el = $(event.target);
        post = el.parent().parent().attr("data-post");
        $(".loading").show();
        // we have vote and event variables now, lets send vote to server.
        var data = JSON.stringify({
            rate: vote, id: post
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/blog/rate",
            dataType: "Json",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (responseData) {
                alert(responseData);
                window.location = responseData.redirect;
            }
        });

    });
```

and in Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Rate(int id, int rate)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = _db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
                PostScore score = new PostScore();
                score.BlogPostId = id;
                score.Score = rate;
                score.UserId = user.UserId;
                _db.PostScores.Add(score);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                // get last error
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    while (ex.InnerException != null)
                        ex = ex.InnerException;

            }
        }
        else
            return Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("Login", "Account") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("Index") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When i run it, retrieve json data `{"redirect":"/Account/Login"}` for jquery. and redirect to `http://localhost:2478/undefined` (return undefined for redirect).

if i return `Json(Url.Action("Login", "Account") , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` it redirect to `http://localhost:2478/%22/Account/Login%22`

How to retrieve a url data from controller?

Comment: put it inside a variable and then return from json like:  var url="/Account/Login" ..... return Json(new { redirect = url }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Thanks, i use a variable, but it is return `undefined ` again :(

Comment: alert(responseData.redirect);...is saying undefined???

Comment: It is return empty alert.

Comment: just read this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564341/returning-json-object-from-controller-action-to-jquery

Comment: Thanks, i use this link, but return `undefined ` :(

Comment: can you check via firebug what json response is coming?

Comment: I use firebug, it return "{"redirect":"/Account/Login"}" . return string value

Comment: dataType: Json -> json? try it.

Comment: @ar.gorgin see my answer hope it gives you understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to firebug console you are getting response as string so parse it to json as it is returned as string:

**"{"redirect":"/Account/Login"}"**

```
success: function (response) {
     var data = JSON.parse(response);    
     window.location.href = data.redirect;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working fine for me

```
return Json(new { Redirect = "/Account/Login" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and ajax success

```
success: function (response) {    
     window.location.href = response.Redirect ;    
}
```

Comment: it is return `"{"redirect":"/Account/Login"}"` for `response` and return `undefined` for `response.Redirect`